# Non overlapping labels in a scatterplot with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, label, scatter-plot

I would like to draw a d3.js scatter plot with non overlapping labels. Each label has X and Y coordinates, but they can move "a little bit", so that they do not overlap. I do not know how to implement this idea.

Here is a sample of the data :

```
LABEL   X_AXIS  Y_AXIS
Clotilde    23.8    168
Ninon   22.1    131
Anouk   21.0    119
Raphaelle   20.9    158
Adele   20.7    305
Capucine    20.6    160
Diane   20.1    293
Flore   19.3    161
Apolline    19.1    188
Iris    18.6    118
Victoire    18.0    205
Louise  17.9    1076
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted a working example of your scatter plot in which we can answer your question more accurately as answers could very depending on how you are implementing the chart. You can post this on jsfiddle.net or another simulate site.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/coulmont/5974977 is a first draft

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of help, here is the non-overlapping scatterplot

http://coulmont.com/varia/bac2013.html

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Mind if I steal it?